# Four way competition for Machine Learning PhD admission. Which background increases the odds of getting in?

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say there are students from four backgrounds (Mathematics, Applied Mathematics, Computer Science and Statistics) all from top programs. They are applying to a machine learning PhD program at a top American university.

1. In terms of getting in, which background is most favorable?
2. What can the pure math student do to improve their chances of getting in?
3. Would a double degree in any combination of the above fields be more favorable?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Sir I was thinking something like Machine Learning at MIT/Carnegie Mellon/Stanford/Berkeley. If it's good enough for them, it's probably good enough for many others too (though I know individual universities differ in research areas, I think this is too general a question for these differences to really matter?).

Comment: Can you give a couple of sample URLs of the programs in question

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Sorry for the delay (timezone difference). I'm posting links for each program and their associated labs.

Comment: MIT program: http://www.eecs.mit.edu/academics-admissions/graduate-program

Lab: CSAIL (Link is down, so posting one level up). http://www.eecs.mit.edu/research/17

Comment: Stanford program: https://cs.stanford.edu/academics/phd

Lab: SAIL https://cs.stanford.edu/research/ai

Comment: Berkeley program: https://eecs.berkeley.edu/resources/grads/phd 

Lab: BAIR https://bair.berkeley.edu/

Comment: CMU program: https://www.ml.cmu.edu/academics/ml-phd.html

Labs (multiple): https://www.ml.cmu.edu/research/

Comment: This is a question to the folks at your target universities who actually make these decisions. We cannot read their mind.